# What is the eclipse plugin update release mechanism?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to emulate the eclipse update mechanism in my custom Eclipse RCP Application. So, I want to konw that If Eclipse team updates one plug-in, what they will they do for:

1. the version of this plug-in;
2. the version of the feature which include this plug-in;( maybe there are so many features ) ;
3. the version of the feature which include the feature above;( maybe there are so many features ) ;

I care more about the features, they will all be rebuild ?

If anyone knows this, can give me some advice, thanks a lot!

Comment: Eclipse is open source, so you can find out for yourself by looking into the history: [Eclipse Platform](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/), [Eclipse JDT](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/), etc. For plugins a baseline is set to be able to check via [API Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-api-tools/) the correctness of semantic versioning. It's up to you how to version your features. Eclipse projects often bind version of their features to the release. The version of your application should be driven by marketing and is unrelated to the versions of your plugins and features.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express clearly. I'm concerned more about the build logic actually.

If I update one plug-in and upgrade its version, I have to rebuild all features which include this plug-in ? Because I find that I only upgrad this plug-in version, and put it in the "plugins" directory, Eclipse will not use the newer plug-in but the older one.

Comment: You can't just put things in the plugins directory, you have to build proper update sites and use Check for Updates - so that means, yes, you have to rebuild everything, and it needs to have changed version numbers.